# Pulling (JSON) data using Node.js to a PHP MVC (CI)

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, codeigniter, apache2

I have always used PHP for codeing 
(currently work with CI Ubuntu server).

I am working on a web-app that gets data from APIs mostly, and now I have a new task including scraping. 
I figured out that scraping pages that have scroll ajax autoload using PHP might make my life miserable and almost impossible to do - so since I'm working mostly on the web - checking out Node.js can be an awesome experience - Especially when my web-app is kinda slow since I'm working with slow APIs and pulling A LOT of data and Node.js might solve some of these problems.

After installing Node,js on my apache server, and setting the proxies -

*(http://www.codingtricks.biz/run-nodejs-application-apache/)
(https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/01/run-nodejs-application-lamp-stack-server/)
(http://blog.podrezo.com/making-node-js-work-with-apache/ - "What about only partially redirecting to node?" is what I might need?)*

All tutorials I have found include EXPRESS but currently I'm using CI MVC and it's important for me to use PHP as my framework, and use Node.js more for API calls and displaying instant and dynamic data when needed.

Where do I install the main Node.js folder in my project? 
How do I call do I call models from within CI? (even with variables)

Comment: You can use CURL in PHP to call NodeJS apis

Comment: And where do I implement the main model directory and files for node.js?

Comment: you can make a folder name node, and put all the nodejs files in same structure in that folder

Comment: The only way you can access nodejs from php or php from nodejs is by api calls, because both run on different technology

Comment: oh and set the proxy to /api and call files from there like explained here: http://blog.podrezo.com/making-node-js-work-with-apache/ under "What about only partially redirecting to node?" is what I might need?"

Comment: in CI, Make a separate controller to do this, put output content type to application/json and call models from there.

Comment: So you say that I cant actually display immediate data to a user using node.js in that way but use only api calls. fine, in that case, do you think adding NGINX and using its reverse proxy to apache2 will help me display immediate data to users?

Comment: yes, I have done that before

Comment: sure why not, ironicindian@gmail.com

Comment: It's crazy, haven't found not one normal full tutorial that explains Apache2+NGINX+NODE.JS

Comment: it because these techs are new, but you'll get blogs soon